# Замена значения HTML атрибута Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Час добрый
Нужно заменить на странице этот элемент:

```
<span class="test">
    <br data-text="true">
</span>
```

На такой:

```
<span class="test">
    <span id="test">TEXT EXAMPLE</span>
</span>
```

Страница загружается при помощи selenium с вебдрайвером Fierfox

Пока искал ответы на данный вопрос, наткнулся на https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-beginners/thread2432613.html , но к сожалению не смог преобразовать данный способ под свою задачу 

Заранее благодарен ответам

Comment: именно так и делается, посидите, подумайте над текстом. у вас только две строки  elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="post_message_13472399"]')  html = driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML=arguments[1];", elem,'НОВЫЙ ТЕКСТ ЭТОГО DIV')

Comment: @nexoma в таком примере заменяется только текст внутри элемента, а не весь элемент. С этим и проблема

Comment: уровнем выше замените